# Unable to install httpd on DigitalOcean

Tags: apache, ubuntu, digital-ocean

I tried running `apt-get install httpd` to install the Apache HTTP Server, but I got the following error:

```
    Package httpd is a virtual package provided by:
  yaws 1.94-1
  webfs 1.21+ds1-8.1
  tntnet 2.1-2+deb7u1
  ocsigenserver 2.1-1
  ocsigen 1.3.4-2+b12
  nginx-naxsi-ui 1.2.1-2.2+wheezy3
  nginx-naxsi 1.2.1-2.2+wheezy3
  nginx-light 1.2.1-2.2+wheezy3
  nginx-full 1.2.1-2.2+wheezy3
  nginx-extras 1.2.1-2.2+wheezy3
  mini-httpd 1.19-9.3
  micro-httpd 20051212-15
  lighttpd 1.4.31-4+deb7u3
  ebhttpd 1:1.0.dfsg.1-4.3
  bozohttpd 20111118-1
  boa 0.94.14rc21-3.1
  apache2-mpm-worker 2.2.22-13+deb7u3
  apache2-mpm-prefork 2.2.22-13+deb7u3
  apache2-mpm-itk 2.2.22-13+deb7u3
  apache2-mpm-event 2.2.22-13+deb7u3
  aolserver4-daemon 4.5.1-15.1
  aolserver4-core 4.5.1-15.1

You should explicitly select one to install.
```

Can someone help please. I am really stuck at this point. I have looked up various posts on ubuntu forums, etc.

Comment: Here is the answer `You should explicitly select one to install.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like CS GO said, it is really important to specifically select a server to install. There are 3 major server packages that are used. Apache webserver, NGINX webserver and Lighthttpd.

You're on the right track to getting it installed, but unlike CentOS where the service name would indeed be httpd, on Ubuntu they are packaged under a product name. Assuming you want to install Apache on your server the command would be

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

alternatively to install lighttpd or nginx, replace apache2 with either lighttpd or nginx-full

Good luck